# How to remove extra brackets from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, array

I have a list which looks like the following:

```
   list1={{{a,b,c},{a1,b1,c1},{an, bn,cn}},{{f,j,k},{f1,j1,k1},{fn, jn,kn}}}
```

And I need it to be as follows:

```
   {{a,b,c},{a1,b1,c1},{an, bn,cn},{f,j,k},{f1,j1,k1},{fn, jn,kn}}
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: If you put brackets on the left like this `{list1}={{{a,b,c},{a1,b1,c1},{an, bn,cn}},{{f,j,k},{f1,j1,k1},{fn, jn,kn}}}`, `list1` will not contain the outer brackets that appear on the right.

Answer (score 9):

```
Join @@ list1
```

```
Catenate @ list1
```

```
Flatten[list1, 1]
```

All return

> {{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {an, bn, cn}, {f, j, k}, {f1, j1, k1}, {fn, jn, kn}}

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're most welcome

Answer (score 5):

Using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[list1, m_ :> Splice@m, {1}]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {an, bn, cn}, {f, j, k}, {f1, j1, k1}, {fn, jn, kn}}

Answer (score 5):

One more way

```
Level[list1, {2}]

(* {{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {an, bn, cn}, {f, j, k}, 
    {f1, j1, k1}, {fn, jn, kn}} *)
```

And another:

```
Splice /@ list1

(* {{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {an, bn, cn}, {f, j, k}, 
    {f1, j1, k1}, {fn, jn, kn}} *)
```

**Explanation/acknowledgement**

Exploring the [neat method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/301121/106) posted by
@Gustavo Delfino (using `Query`):

```
Query[All, Splice] // Normal

(* Map[Splice] *)
```

Comment: (+1) Excellent use of `Level`! :)

Comment: Something I saw you did in another post: `Delete[#, 0] & /@ list1`

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[list1, v_?VectorQ, All]

Sequence @@@ list1

ArrayReshape[list1, {Times @@ (Most@Dimensions@list1), 
  Last@Dimensions@list1}]
```

---

> {{a, b, c}, {a1, b1, c1}, {an, bn, cn}, {f, j, k}, {f1, j1, k1}, {fn,
> jn, kn}}

Answer (score 3):

Can also be done like this:

`Query[All, Splice][list1]`